# How to effectively prefetch multiple columns in one model?

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure if my way of prefetching sets of items is correct. Its nested reverse foreign key fetch (another model objects and other objects).

```
class Created(models.Model):
    created = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Category(Created):
    category = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)


class Question(Created):
    question = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="questions"
    )

    @property
    def correct_answer(self):
        return self.questions.filter(correct=True)

class Answer(Created):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="answers")
```

query:

`Category.objects.prefetch_related("questions", "questions__answers")`

The above statement gives me 3 queries which I believe is too much. Or maybe it's okay? Appreciate any feedback :)

Comment: One query for each model is expected, that's how `prefetch_related` works

Comment: So the above approach seems to be fine? Or maybe there is more effecient way?

Comment: If you need to fetch all objects from all three related models it looks fine as a baseline - depending on what you are doing with the result of your query there may be optimisations but you don't give enough details

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified your code by adding `DateTimeField` and inheriting `models.Model` in category class, also i have remove `correct_answer` method because if you want to fetch for question or answer objects you can not do it by defining a function inside a class object that you have created before.

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Created(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True 

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200) 
    
class Question(Created):
    question = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="questions")
    
class Answer(Created):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="answers")
```

In this example i want to show that objects have defined properly his methods and fields, i certainly do not know why you want to use `correct_answer` but if you want to get objects that have a specific value, like `correct` variable you can use `filter` method to get a `QuerySet` instance.

interactive interpreter

```
>>> from .models import *
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> category = Category.objects.create(category="normal")
>>> question = Question.objects.create(question="text", category=category, created=timezone.now())
>>> answer = Answer.objects.create(name="name", correct=True, question=question, created=timezone.now())
>>> answer.created
datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 4, 7, 15, 30, 899071, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> Answer.objects.filter(correct=True)
<QuerySet [<Answer: Answer object (1)>]>
>>> Category.objects.prefetch_related("questions", "questions__answers")[0].category
'normal'
```